# Format hover data labels Plotly R

Tags: r, ggplotly, r-plotly

I am trying to format the data labels that appear when I hover over part of a chart I have created using Plotly. The label is currently showing like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jKpE.png). I would like for the label to only show profit.

My code for creating the plot is:

```
output$monthlyProfits <- renderPlotly({
ggplot(profitTemp, aes(x = Date, y = Profit)) + geom_line(aes(text=Profit), 
colour = "Blue")
```

How do I format the data label so that it will not show the X axis and only show the Y axis (profit)? I have tried with `aes(text=Profit)` but the X axis still shows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is more flexible to customize the plots that are directly made in `plotly`, however the requested operation is also possible using `ggplotly`. Here is an example on the iris data set:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot)
```

To define the hover info:

```
plot_ly(data = iris,
        x = ~Sepal.Length,
        y = ~Petal.Length,
        color = ~Species,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~Species)
```

[image]

to do so with ggplotly leave the text argument blank when calling ggplot:

```
z <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species))+
  geom_point()
```

and set the argument `tooltip` to `ggplotly`:

```
ggplotly(z, tooltip="Species")
```

[image]

compared to:

```
z <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, color = Species))+
  geom_point(aes(text = Species)) 

ggplotly(z)
```

[image]

EDIT: custom text:

```
plot_ly(data = iris,
        x = ~Sepal.Length,
        y = ~Petal.Length,
        color = ~Species,
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste(Species,
                      '</br></br>', Petal.Length))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is a great help. How can I put 2 names in the data label? I have tried `ggplotly(produceMonthlyPlot, tooltip="QuantitySold", "</b>", "Product")` but it is only showing the `QuantitySold` variable and not the `Product` variable.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this with `ggplotly`, check edit on how to perform it with plotly.

Answer (score 0):

To your second question in the comments (sorry for not leaving a comment - lacking the reputation to do so):

just supply a vector to the tooltip attribute, e.g.

```
ggplotly(produceMonthlyPlot, tooltip=c("QuantitySold","Product"))
```

With that you can control what should be displayed and what not.